# Python renaming strings

Tags: python, split, filenames, strip, renaming

Kinda dumb question but I got stuck. So I got this

```
print (image_files[index].split(".")[0]).split("/")[1].split
```

which gives the following output:

```
sun5_face_righteye
```

How can I keep stripping or splitting the string so I get only:

```
righteye
```

Thank you

Comment: Show the content of `image_files`

Comment: Split it again on `-` and get the third element

Comment: @MosesKoledoye images_files gives eyes/sun5_face_righteye.jpg

Comment: @Noelkd does the job! Thanks, but Im facing another problem, most images are name : 57268-face-_tracker_face_righteye, in this case how do I get only the righteye?

Comment: Since you're working with paths, you should consider using `os.path`, particularly for more complex operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
>>> s = "sun5_face_righteye"
>>> s.split("_")[2]
'righteye'
```

**Edit1:**

```
>>> s = "xxxxx-face-_tracker_face_righteye"
>>> s.split("_")[-1]
'righteye'
```

**Edit2 :**

```
>>> s = "sun5_face_righteye"
>>> s.split("_face_")[0]
'sun5'
>>> s = "57268-face-_tracker_face_lefteye"
>>> s.split("_face_")[0]
'57268-face-_tracker'
```

Comment: does the job! Thanks, but Im facing another problem, most images are name : xxxxx-face-_tracker_face_righteye, in this case how do I get only the righteye?
xxxx are increasing numbers

Comment: @TiagoSilva Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry If im being annoying, but I got a different situation now.
From "sun5_face_righteye" or "57268-face-_tracker_face_lefteye" I need to remove "_face_righteye" or "_face_lefteye" Is it possible? @Harsha Biyani

Comment: @TiagoSilva : Edied ans again.

Comment: Perfect once again! Life saver @Harsha Biyani

Answer (score 2):

As you're looking at filenames, you might want to use `os.path.splitext`:

```
import os

fpath = "eyes/sun5_face_righteye.jpg"
fname = os.path.splitext(fpath)[0].split("_")[-1]

print fname
```

`os.path.splitext(fname)` extracts the filepath and extension, taking index `0` of this gets just the filepath without the extension. Splitting this on `_` and taking the last element gets the `righteye` you need.

**EDIT:** In response to the comment, you could get "face_righteye" using the following:

```
import os

fpath = "eyes/sun5_face_righteye.jpg"
fname = "_".join(os.path.splitext(fpath)[0].split("_")[-2:])

print fname
```

Changing our index from `-1` to `-2:` gets us a list of the last two elements (rather than the last element alone). Using `"_".join` re-combines these elements with an underscore.

Comment: Sorry If im being annoying, but I got a different situation now.
From sun5_face_righteye or 57268-face-_tracker_face_lefteye I need to remove "_face_righteye" or "_face_lefteye" Is it possible? @asongtoruin

Comment: @TiagoSilva no worries - I've updated this for you (though without a leading underscore)